# How to have typechking on fastify handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I have a simple fastify server like this.

```js
import { Static, Type } from "@sinclair/typebox";

const UserSchema = Type.Object({
  username: Type.String(),
  email: Type.String({ format: "email" }),
  age: Type.Number(),
});

const UserResponseSchema = Type.Object({
  name: Type.String(),
});

type UserResponseSchemaType = Static<typeof UserResponseSchema>;
type UserSchemaType = Static<typeof UserSchema>;

// ---------------------

interface createUserRouteInterFace {
  Body: UserSchemaType;
  Reply: UserResponseSchemaType;
}

async function indexRoutes(fastify: FastifyInstance) {
  fastify.post<createUserRouteInterFace>(
    "/create-user",
    { schema: { body: UserSchema, response: { 200: UserResponseSchema } } },
    createUserController // my problem is in here !
  );
}
```

As you know if I put an inline anonymous function instead of `createUserController` in here I'm going to get type-checking for free but in the larger project as you know it's a mess.
So I have a different file that I use for my controllers. and for example a simple controller is like this.

```js
// controllers.ts
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from "fastify";
import { UserSchemaType } from "../somewhere";

export async function createUserController(
  req: FastifyRequest<{ Body: UserSchemaType }>,
  reply: FastifyReply
) {
  const { username } = req.body;
  return reply.send({ username });
}
```

with this solution everything works fine but with the cost of losing type-checking of `FastifyReply`

So my question is do you have any idea of how to write a controller function without losing type checking?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the `type` method.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
// controllers.ts
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from "fastify";
import { UserSchemaType } from "../somewhere";

export async function createUserController(
  req: FastifyRequest<{ Body: UserSchemaType }>,
  reply: FastifyReply
) {
  const { username } = req.body;
  const response: UserResponseSchemaType = {name:username};
  reply.type<UserResponseSchemaType>().send(response);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: I see. can you provide more info, on what happened after this? Or provide any error log?

Comment: ```reply.type``` doesn't accept generic types. https://imgur.com/a/ZfS6ETx

Comment: Okay. You can use the serializer method then. reply.send(response, {serializer: (value)=> JSON.stringify(value), schema: UserResponseSchemaType});